# "(из) кости" - ударение в форме родительного падежа

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: *из слоновой кОсти* или *из слоновой костИ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "кость" не меняет ударения в косвенных падежах единственного числа. 
Из к**о**сти, для к**о**сти, о к**о**сти - и т.д.

Только в предложном падеже в значении местного (с предлогами НА и В), а также в большинстве косвенных падежей множественного происходит смещение ударения на окончания.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x

Правильно: *из слоновой к**о**сти*.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже так думала, просто хотелось подтвердить свои знания!

Comment: Юлия Ермакова, Не стоит благодарности. У вас есть кнопочка-галочка "принять ответ". Пользуйте её в дальнейшем как благодарность.